# How do I parse (using TryParse) a string in a method to a global int

Tags: c#, methods, global-variables

I'm struggling to parse user input to a global integer

When I give the global scoreString a value after declaring it like this --- static string scoreString = "55"; --- it works

```
    static string scoreString = "55";
    static bool scoreBool = int.TryParse(scoreString, out score);
    static int score;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("====STUDENT AVERAGE CHECKER====");
        AverageMaker();

        if (scoreBool)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parsing good");
            Console.WriteLine(score);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parsing fail");
            Console.WriteLine(score);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    public static void AverageMaker()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-----Enter score---");
        scoreString = Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: In `AverageMaker()` you are not resetting `scoreBool = int.TryParse(scoreString, out score)`. It's set to true at initialization, but never changed

Comment: you need to parse after you set new value to `scoreString`? isn't it obvious?

Comment: "Why so static?"

Comment: @Selvin I think OP is victim to a misconception, that `static bool scoreBool = int.TryParse(scoreString, out score);` works like some kind of macro? It may be ovious to us, but I cannot say I may not have had the same misconception if I was just to start with programming.

Comment: There are lot of improvements you can do in your code

Comment: @Fildor then changing `=` to `=>` should help :)

Comment: @Selvin Well, I think the code could use more improvements than that, anyway. But it will definitely go into my "code to torture interviewees with"-Folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are of parsing `scoreString` out side of `Main()` function. Parse it inside `AverageMaker()` function, after reading string from `Console`

something like,

```
public static void AverageMaker()
{
    Console.WriteLine("-----Enter score---");
    scoreString = Console.ReadLine();
    scoreBool = int.TryParse(scoreString, out score); //This was missing
}
```

Comment: In case it's not obvious, code outside the functions is run before the functions, so the parse was occurring before scoreString had been entered by the user.

Comment: @RobinBennett, completely agree. That's what I want to convey here. right place to parse string to int

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. Thanks for the answer Mr Telkikar and thanks for the explanation Mr Bennett. It's a tricky and I thought I was losing my mind with but I'll remember the tip!!

Answer (score -3):

Remove new line character as result of readline :  scoreString = scoreString.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty); and try to parse

Comment: Since when `Console.ReadLine();` returns the input with a `\n` ?

Comment: That's _not_ the problem, Oleg.

Comment: Code that you post is not try parse it again  to scoreString

Comment: I edited the code , please retry if you get the value from readline again

Comment: Since when `Console.ReadLine();` returns the input with a `\r\n` ?

Comment: Again:  your code in averagemaker need  reinit the value to scoreString  from readline

Comment: @Oleg indeed, but your answer doesn't answer the question

Comment: Oleg, please. Don't write the solution in the comments. Write it in your answer. The text that _is_ currently in your answer is invalid and has nothing to do with the question.